# mongoc_collection_update how to shorten notation

Tags: c, mongodb

is there a shorter way to update an existing field within a doc or insert it (directly within the doc as leaf, not as sub doc) than having to have a "child" leaf after the "$set" ?
I am aware there are bulk updates, but I am not sure how to use them, what could be the shortest quickest way for an update in C of existing doc ?

{
"_id" : "02AE0001",
"fields_1" : { "$binary" : "", "$type" : "00" },
"fields_2" : { "$binary" : "", "$type" : "00" } <-- say I want to update only this field leaving the other fields in the doc alone
}

```
        bson_t *query=bson_new();
        bson_t *update=bson_new();
        bson_t *update_child=bson_new();

        for(...)
        {

            bson_reinit(query);
            BSON_APPEND_UTF8(query, "_id", axxstring);// key, value
            //bson_t *update = BCON_NEW ("$set", "{", 
                //fieldstring, BCON_BIN(BSON_SUBTYPE_BINARY,(uint8_t*)m_buf, m_len),
            //"}");
            bson_reinit(update);
            bson_reinit(update_child);


// is there a shorter way to update an existing field within a doc or insert it (directly within the doc as leaf, not as sub doc)
            BSON_APPEND_BINARY (update_child, fieldstring, BSON_SUBTYPE_BINARY,
                    (uint8_t*)(*itr).second.m_staticdynamicfields[subgroup].m_buf, 
                    (*itr).second.m_staticdynamicfields[subgroup].m_len 
                );
            bson_append_document (update, "$set", -1, update_child);




            if (!mongoc_collection_update (collection, MONGOC_UPDATE_UPSERT, query, update, wc, &error)) // MONGOC_UPDATE_UPSERT creates the record when importing static fields from .upd file
            {
                error
            }
            
            }
            
        }
        mongoc_write_concern_destroy (wc);
        bson_destroy(query);
        bson_destroy(update);
```

Comment: Check out the example at http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/1.4.0/updating-document.html

Comment: I am searching for a way that doesn't entail allocations with BCON_NEW, for speed sake, i.e. reuse the bson